# From struts 2.0.14 to 2.3.16.1. Class not found for RuleSet

Tags: java, security, deployment, struts2, digest

for security reason I have to update the reference of struts2-tiles-plugin  from 2.0.X to 2.3.16.1.
I update my web.xml with:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but when I deploy the application an error appear:

```
12:20:57,851 ERROR [[/pectWeb]] StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/RuleSet
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin.processFile(JobInitializationPlugin.java:397)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin.start(JobInitializationPlugin.java:375)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:1919)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:397)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:147)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet.init(QuartzInitializerServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4417)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet from BaseClassLoader@1665a0d{vfsfile:/D:/Server/jboss-as/server/all/conf/jboss-service.xml}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:477)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 72 more
12:20:57,853 ERROR [[/pectWeb]] Servlet /pectWeb threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet from BaseClassLoader@1665a0d{vfsfile:/D:/Server/jboss-as/server/all/conf/jboss-service.xml}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:477)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin.processFile(JobInitializationPlugin.java:397)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin.start(JobInitializationPlugin.java:375)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:1919)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:397)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:147)
    at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet.init(QuartzInitializerServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4417)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

There is the dependency to commons-digest, also in target folder there's the jar, but this error occurs, I don't know why

This is my pom.xml

```
 ...
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-providedr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>pectWeb</finalName>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igfay.jfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfig</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                <groupId>logkit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.infocamere.pect.pect-jlx</groupId>
        <artifactId>pectCommons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <groupId>quartz</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>legalmail-client</artifactId>
                <groupId>it.infocert.legalmail</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>imq</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.messaging.mq</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: You should update all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For struts 2.3.16.1 you must use commons-digester-2.1.jar

If you are using maven, make sure you added

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also make sure there are no other commons-digester jars in your application lib or server commons lib folder.

Comment: I have: 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.16.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>

And no other lib in my project or in server commons lib

Comment: is commons-digester jars in your lib?!

Comment: Yes, with 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
     <groupId>logkit</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
     <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: May be the commons-digester jars is corrupted? Try to re download it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved setting provided my pectCommons dependency and deploying my Ear with my EJB before my WebApplication.